# Reasoning about relatively prime factors of consecutive integers

Tags: inequality, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Let:

- $n,m,x$ be any integer with $n$ being even
- $D_n(m,x)$ be the count of integers $i$ where:

> - $m-x \le i < m$
> - There exists a prime $p \le x$ such that $p \nmid n$ but $p | i$

Examples:

$D_6(0,5) = 1$  { -5 } with $p=5$

$D_6(20,5) = 1$  { 15 } with $p=5$

I am trying to see whether it is always the case that:

$$D_n(m,x) \le D_n(0,x) + 1$$

I am having trouble either finding a counter example or finding the argument why it is true.

Intuitively, I would assume that it is not true.  That there should exist $m,x,n$ such that $D_n(m,x) > D_n(0,x)+1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A counter example is $m = 22$, $n = 6$ and $x = 8$. In this case, $D_6(0,8) = 2$ since, for $-8 \le i \lt 0$, the only primes $p \le 8$ which don't divide $6$ are $5$ and $7$, but the values of $i$ that they do divide are just $-5$ and $-7$.

On the other hand, you have $D_6(22,8) = 4$ since checking $14 \le i \lt 22$ gives $5 \mid 15$ and $5 \mid 20$, plus $7 \mid 14$ and $7 \mid 21$.

Since $4 \gt 2 + 1$, this gives a case where $D_n(m,x) \gt D_n(0,x) + 1$ to show your condition does not always hold.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks very much.  This really helps me to build my intuition on this topic!

Comment: @LarryFreeman You're welcome. I actually need to work on my intuition since I originally thought there would not be a counter-example, so yours was better than mine, until I realized I was not considering the question appropriately, at which time I thought of this counter-example.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I have the following counterexample in the comments (this one was incorrect): $n = 6$, $m = 50$, $x = 10$.

The counter-example I found was $m = 500$, $n = 2$ and $x = 10$. Here, $D_n(m,x) = 10$ and $D_n(0,x) \leq 8$ (since -8, -4, -2 are powers of 2 multiplied by $\pm 1$). This would violate the first inequality you state.

I include my thought process (to follow) as I noted in your bio you are a math enthusiast and aiming for grad school. Also, as I am the same, I thought it'd be for me a nice exercise.

My thought process was that if we take a really large $m$ and a small $x$, more numbers from the set $\{-x, \dots, -1\}$ would not be included in the count $D_n(0,x)$ compared to $D_n(m,x)$. For instance, in my example, for the quantity $D_n(m,x)$, one must only check that the numbers $490, \dots 499$ are not purely powers of 2. It is easy to generate counter-examples here in the sense that the gaps between successive powers of 2 (and any positive integer in general) gets very large very fast. Indeed, for the numbers of smaller absolute value in my example ($\{-10, \dots, -1\}$), there "is a greater chance" of there being powers of 2.

Comment: You state $D_n(m,x) = 10$ for $m = 500$, $n = 2$ and $x = 10$. Based on the question conditions, this means all $10$ values between $490$ and $499$, inclusive, must have a factor of $3$, $5$ or $7$ (as those are the only primes less than $10$ other than $2$). However, such as shown in https://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/10000.txt, you have $491$ and $499$ being prime, so they can't be divisible by $3$, $5$ or $7$, which means $D_{2}(500,10) \le 8$.

Comment: Oh whoops, it looks like I mixed up the roles of the variables. Let me take another look.

Comment: I don't believe that this is a counter example.  By my calculations: $D_2(500,10) = 2$ since $491, 493, 499$  are not divisible by a prime less than $10$ and $D_2(0,10) = 4$ so that $2 \le 4+1$

Comment: @LarryFreeman wouldn't $D_2(0,10) = #\{ -10, -9, -7, -6, -5, -3, -1\} = 7$?

Comment: @LarryFreeman I have the following: $D_6(0,10) = \# \{ -5, -7\} = 2$ and $D_6(50,10) = \# \{ 40, 42, 45, 49\} = 4$, but $4 \leq 2+1$ is false.

Comment: @Azhao Thanks for the correction.  i did forget the even number.  $-1$ which is not divisible by a prime $p \le 10$.  So $D_2(0,10) = \{-10, -9, -7, -6, -5, -3 \} = 6$. $D_2(500,10) = 5$ from \{ 490, 492, 494, 495, 497\}.  I had ignored the even numbers which would still apply in relation to my definition.  :-)

Comment: @Azhao17 Your updated counter-example is still not correct. In this case, $D_6(0,10) =$ #{$-5,-7,-10$} $= 3$, since the condition is for $m-x \le i \lt m$ which translates to $-10 \le i \lt 0$, so $-10$ is included in the checking.