# Counting consecutive integers that are divisible by primes relatively prime to an arbitrary $n$

Tags: prime-numbers, solution-verification, chinese-remainder-theorem, prime-gaps

Let:

- $c > 0, n, m, x > 0$ be an integers
- $p\#$ be the [primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) of $p$
- $D_n(m,x)$ be the count of integers $i$ where:

> - $m-x \le i < m$
> - There exists a prime $p$ that $p \nmid n$ but $p | i$

It occurs to me that for any $c$, there exists $n,m,x$ such that:

$$D_n(m,x) \ge D_n(0,x) + c$$

Here is the argument:

(1)  From well-known properties [see (20)] of [Bertrand's Postulate](http://www.zyymat.com/ramanujans-proof-of-bertrands-postulate.html), there exists $x$ for any such $c$ such that:

$$\frac{x}{2} < p_0 < p_1 < p_2 < \dots < p_c < x$$

where each $p_i$ is a prime

(2)  $D_{p_0\#}(0,x) = c$

(3)  Using the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), there exists $u$ such that:

- $p_c | u$
- $p_{c-1} | u+1$
- $p_{c-2} | u+2$
- $\vdots$
- $p_1 | u+c-1$

(4)  Let $m = x + u$

(5)  It follows that:

$$D_{p_0\#}(m,x) = 2c$$

Is my reasoning correct?  Did I make a mistake?

---

Edit:  Fixed a minor mistake identified by John Omielan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've done is correct. I have just a couple of suggestions, and you made a minor mistake.

For your ($1$), an alternative is to use that the [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) shows the prime gaps eventually have an upper bound which is an arbitrarily small multiplier of the prime number. As stated in the [Upper bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Upper_bounds) section of Wikipedia's "Prime gap" article,

> For every $\epsilon \gt 0$, there is a number $N$ such that for all $n \gt N$
>
> $\; \; \; \; g_{n} \lt p_{n}\epsilon$.

You can just choose $\epsilon = \frac{1}{c + 1}$ in your case.

The other suggestion is you could have explicitly mentioned that, for each $p_i$, there is also another integer $u + (c - i) + p_i$ which is less than $x$, is divisible by $p_i$, and is not divisible by any $p_j$ where $j \neq i$ (so it won't be double-counted). This means it's an additional integer to include in the $D_n(m,x)$ count, which then explains how you got the extra $c$ to get $D_{p_0\#}(m,x) = 2c$.

As for the small mistake, your $p_1 | u + c$ should be $p_1 | u + c - 1$ instead.

When I determined the counter-example for your related question [Reasoning about relatively prime factors of consecutive integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3746527/602049), I thought it'll also be the case for any integer larger than $1$, i.e., $c$ in your question here. I didn't consider then how to possibly prove it, but I'm glad to see you've done it here with your post.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.  Yes, I need to go deeper into the Prime Number Theorem.  I appreciate the reference.  This will help motivate me to spend the time to go thoroughly through the elementary version of the proof.  :-)